# jQuery Sortable - dragged not showing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the jQuery Sortable plugin for a ranking list and the functionality is working almost 100% but I'm having an issue with the 'dragged' item.

I click an item and I'm able to drag it - you can see the placeholder too, but you can't see the transparent current item you're dragging.

I can track it with Chrome Dev tools but it's like it's completely invisible.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="ranking">
    <div class="ranking-wrap">
    <h3>How would you rank each design?</h3>
    <ol id="rank-list">
        <li>Design <strong>A</strong> 
        <label for="rank-1" class="offscreen">Rank of design 1</label>
                        <input type="number" id="rank-1" value="1" name="rank1"> 
                    </li>
        <li>Design <strong>B</strong>
                        <label for="rank-2" class="offscreen">Rank of design 2</label>
                        <input type="number" id="rank-2" value="2" name="rank2">
                    </li>
        <li>Design <strong>C</strong>

                        <label for="rank-3" class="offscreen">Rank of design 3</label>
                        <input type="number" id="rank-3" value="3" name="rank3">
                    </li>
        <li>Design <strong>D</strong>
                        <label for="rank-4" class="offscreen">Rank of design 4</label>
                        <input type="number" id="rank-4" value="4" name="rank4">
                    </li>
        <li>Design <strong>E</strong>
                        <label for="rank-5" class="offscreen">Rank of design 5</label>
                        <input type="number" id="rank-5" value="5" name="rank5">                
                    </li>
                </ol>
                </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
    #rank-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#rank-list li { 
    position: relative; 
    min-height: 1em;
    cursor: move;
    font-family: "FS Humana Light";
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em 2.5em;
    background: rgba(238,238,238, .8);
    border: 1px solid #464646;
    margin: .25em auto;
    border-radius: .25em;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 10em;
}

.sm-logo-img {
    width: 32%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: -1.5rem auto -2.2rem 0.5rem;
}

#rank-list li input{
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    top: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #464646;
    font-family: FSHumanaBold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.75em;
    height: 99%;
}

.dragged {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0.5;
   z-index: 2000;
   top: 0;
  left: 5rem;
}

#rank-list li.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(72, 70, 65, .6);
    height: 100%;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas what's messing up the .dragged item or where am I wrong?

I'm using this plug-in: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#docs

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Just ad your js or create full code-snippet.

Comment: Need to see JavaScript code that is being used for this.